# Install numpy to /usr/lib

Tags: python, numpy

I updated numpy to the 1.10.1 version. It is installed to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. How can I install the package to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages instead (for compatibility with other software)?

Comment: Try using `ln -s` which will link the packages. Source -> destination.

Comment: @Poriferous No, don't.  My answer explains why not.

Answer (score 0):

On most modern distros, the only (sane) way to install something in `/usr/lib` is via the system package manager. So you'd use `apt-get` (or whichever similar tool you have - `yum` for Red Hat, `emerge` for Gentoo, etc) to install Numpy there.

The package manager is responsible for the files in the `/usr` tree (except `/usr/local`) and that includes the privilege to remove anything you put there by other means at any point.

The integration with other packages you seem to be seeking is also handled not primarily by installing in a particular location, but by being packaged in accordance with the distro's rules and conventions, which may include distro-specific additions or modifications in order for the package to sit well in the distro-maintained ecosystem.  For a trivial example, if you try to install anything which depends on `python-numpy`, the package of this name needs to be installed.

You basically have the following options;

- Install with your system's package manager (provided they offer a recent enough package for your needs).  On Debian-based distributions, the package name is [`python-numpy`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-numpy&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all)
- Install with `pip` (or some other non-distro tool) and live with the fact that it installs in `/usr/local/lib` (or where-ever you opt to install it).  You probably get a newer version, but it will not be integrated with anything provided by your distro.
- Find a backport -- a package by somebody who packaged a newer version from `pip` into a `*.deb` archive and made it available.  It needs to be said that you are basically giving this person a `root` account on your computer -- tread with care.
- Do it yourself -- create a `*.deb` package from the version you get from `pip` and then install that.  You will probably want to merge any and all of your distro's patches, or live with limited integration (even though integration seems to be what you are looking for).

Many Python modules are simple enough to package, but I have no insight into what it takes to package Numpy.  I would imagine that it is a bit more complex than your average three-file module.